# Why is Logback-spring logging to the wrong file location on a tc-server with several services?

Tags: tomcat, logging, spring-boot, logback

I have 5 services running in the same tc-server, where each one logs to their own directories like so: `/app_logs/service-name/service-name.log`

They are all using the TimeBasedRollingPolicy which is working perfectly except for randomly one of the services on start up will log to a different services log file and keep writing there till tc-server is restarted. (which then another service will do the same thing)

What could be causing this to happen?

Each services application.yml look something like this:

**application.yml**

```
api:
  name: Service-Name
  description: random description.
  version: v1
logging:
  file: /opt/tcserver/dc/app_logs/Service-Name/Service-Name.log
spring:
  application:
    name: Service-Name
```

Each Service shares these two files in the library

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}" />
  <include resource="file-appender.xml" />
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

**file-appender.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- File appender logback configuration provided for import, equivalent to the programmatic initialization performed by 
  Boot -->

<included>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
</included>
```

**Edit**
I was able to figure out what was causing the issue but I still don't really know why or if it is a common problem.

It turned out that, in order to get our services to start faster, we had within our tomcat server.xml file : `startStopThreads=0`. This starts several of our services at once. This cause conflicts with our logback-spring.

Does anyone know why this happened? Has this been fixed in later iterations of Spring Boot? (using 1.3.6.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this situation. In our case, we could get through this issue configuring log4j2 in the spring boot applications, possibly an issue specific to logback.